# Priority/Order int column on Entity Framework association

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-design

I have an association in Entity Framework, but I need to add an attribute/property to it.  I have issues with doing this in Entity Framework anyway (I'd prefer to keep it as an association, but am forced to change it to an Entity in order to add properties to it), but in this specific scenario, I was wondering if there were a better way to do it.

The association table quite simply looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE EntityA_EntityB (
   aId uniqueidentifier,
   bId uniqueidentifier
)
```

The client wants a way to give priority to, or order, the associated EntityBs.  I think the best way to do this is to add an order column (int) to this table, resulting in it looking like this:

```
CREATE TABLE EntityA_EntityB (
   aId uniqueidentifier,
   bId uniqueidentifier,
   order int
)
```

In this scenario, all three columns would make up the primary key.  This seems ok, but it adds quite a bit of complexity into any code that uses this system, because instead of just adding a related EntityB to an EntityA, I have to find the largest "order" number in the `EntityA.EntityBs` collection, and increment it in order to add a new association.

I can make the order column an identity, but this consistently increments the order column regardless of what the values for aId or bId are.  I want something that inserts an order of 0 when a brand new combination of aId and bId is inserted.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order integer doesn't have to be consecutive sequential, you could make the order integer the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE EntityA_EntityB (
   order autoincrementing int
   aId uniqueidentifier,
   bId uniqueidentifier,
)
```

You would have a unique index on (aId, bId, order), and another unique index on (bId, aId, order).

You would just add rows with aId and bId, and the database would take care of the order integer.

Comment: Hi, sorry, should have mentioned.  I need this to be consecutive sequential, so that you can insert a row of (143, 156, 0), and then (143, 156, 1), but then the next row would be (143, 172, 0).

Comment: Then you're going to have to SELECT, INSERT; just like you described in your question.

Comment: I guess so.  I was going to ask if this could be done with triggers, but I suppose Entity Framework is going to demand a value from you regardless.